# Java Flight Control - Keep Last N Minutes record data

Tags: java, java-8, jmc, java-mission-control, jfr

Can someone let me know in Java Flight Control started via Java Mission Control if it is possible to keep only last N minutes of data under continuous recording?

I have gone through this [discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514679?start=0&tstart=0) but I am not able to find where I have to pass the `disk=true` parameter. The options that I have been using looks like below.

[image]

Environment:-

- Java 8
- Mac OS X
- Java Mission Control 5.5.1 (M5.5.1-15, 172852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only disk recordings that allow you to set maximum age or maximum size. So if you use the wizard in JMC you will get a disk recording by default.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

`java -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=disk=true ... app.java`

This will work on JRocket VM.

For Oracle VM you need first to unlock commercial features

`java -XX:+UnlockCommericalFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=disk=true ... app.java`

Comment: You mean while starting jmc like `jmc -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=disk=true`

Comment: It is JVM option. Are you on Oracle or JRocket JVM?

Comment: I am on oracle.

Comment: Not sure, if it is available on Oracle VM, I guess it is a feature of the JRocket VM only. I have edited my answer with full command line.

Comment: The discussion link I have posted in my question is from oracle community there it was mentioned to set `disk=true`. How can I verify if this option is there or not in Oracle JVM?

Comment: I am giving a file name in the UI. You can see the attached screenshot. Shouldn't this mean that `disk=true`? Do I still have to use `FlightRecorderOptions`?